# Which is better? Having class file in the application or getting the data from web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, stored-procedures

I recently took over a project which is partially done. In that project he is using web service for everything i mean for getting each and every data from database.

Ex: I need some data which takes 3 parameters (district code, taluk code an village code)

What is happening is :

1. Creating an xml document using these three parameters
2. Encrypting this xml
3. Sending this XML to the web service
4. Decrypting this XML in web service
5. Retrieving the data through stored procedure with the above mentioned parameters
6. Again generating an xml document for the retrieved data.
7. Again Encrypting this XML and returning this XML to the application
8. Decrypting the returned XML and Generating the datatable with this XML.

I asked him why he has done all this? He said for security purpose.

I feel this is very lengthy and time consuming and what i learned of stored procedures is it secures the application.
My question is why do i need to go through all these procedure when i can have a class file and use stored procedures in my application?

Isn't usage of stored procedures enough to secure my application?
Or should i continue with his technique?(To be frank i disagree with this method)

Note: The parameters are not passed by the user. It will be in the session once the user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the client code resides entirely in the browser side, your mate seems to have created an over-enginereed solution. Actually, you would create a full HTTP interface through Web services if you're developing a full HTML5 app or same backend should be accessed by multiple client technologies.

Security layers can be both implemented *before a request hits a Web service resource* or as a regular concern in a layered software system.

A special note can be made about encryption. If we're talking about Web services through HTTP, encrypting the request body is unnecessary since it can be done in transport level using standard SSL/HTTPS.

Finally, about the XML thing, I guess that you're consuming SOAP services. Maybe your mate either started his project a long time ago or, again, if we're talking about a Web site against a Web service, and he has implemented a SOAP/XML service in the last 5-6 years, he should reconsider using a *convention over configuration* approach like REST...

Comment: @ Matias Thank you. This is a web application and it is completely coded server side.  And user is not allowed to enter anything anywhere in the application. This application majorly has dropdowns and gridviews. So to retreive the data usage of stored procedure is sufficient right? Or should i take care of any other security measures?

Comment: @Rakesh If this is the case, then it seems like your workmate tends to over-engineer solutions...........

Answer (score 0):

This sort of separation is not uncommon in large scale secure web applications in [dual firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)#Dual_firewall) configurations.

If the web application simply called stored procedures directly, you would have to open up port 1433 (or other ODBC port) between the web network zone and the database network zone.  This creates a bit of exposure since the web servers are in a DMZ while your database servers will tend to be in a more secure zone.  Generally speaking you want to keep as many ports sealed up as you can to keep the DMZ contained in case of compromise.

It is shame that your colleague wrote his own solution, since it sounds like most of that functionality would be covered with [SQLXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171779.aspx).